# How do I find the number of rows present in database for a given input value?

Tags: c#, sql, database, counter

I have a working database called `Setup` with the following table.

```
tblPeople
-----------------
people  nchar(50)
occur   int
```

I've got my windows form app to load in user entered data (people) from a text box but I can't figure out how to set it so that if the (people) data has all ready been entered, instead of adding it into the database again, I want it to count in the occur column. For example, if Fred is entered twice, it should show.

```
people occur
------ -----
Fred     2
```

*Code*:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = (@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\John\Desktop\database practise\db1\db1\Setup.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.Connection = connection;

connection.Open();
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblPeople  (people) VALUES (@people)";

try
{
    string[] splittext = textbox1.Text.Split(' '); 
    foreach (string ppl in splittext)
    {
        if (ppl.StartsWith("*")) 
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@people", ppl);
            int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Inserted: " + rowsAffected.ToString());
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

Ignore the string split bit. This works all fine, it's just adding a counter for the occur column I don't know how to do.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just to clarify `IF` `@people` already exists in the database you want to `UPDATE` the existing record with `Occur = Occur + 1`, `ELSE` `INSERT` a new record?

Comment: Yup Spot on! That's exactly what i'm trying to do :)

Answer (score 1):

Before inserting, you have to check whether a record already being inserted with the name, If yes, simply update the count, else, Insert a new record. I would convert this to a stored proc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SavePeople(@peopleName varchar(50))
AS
 BEGIN
   IF EXISTS(SELECT PEOPLE FROM tbl_PEOPLE WHERE PEOPLE=@peopleName)
    BEGIN
      UPDATE tbl_People Set Occur=OCcur+1 WHERE PEOPLE=@peopleName
    END
   ELSE
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO (PEOPLE,OCCUR) VALUES (@peopleNAme,1)
    END

 END
```

I would wrap your code in using statement. I would take out the looping statement from the save method and convert that to a more generic method which acepts a single People Name and save to db. So that you can call this from any scenario(one time or n times in a loop)

```
string con=@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\John\Desktop\database practise\db1\db1\Setup.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"

public bool SavePeople(string peopleName)
{
   try
   {
      using (SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(con))
      {
        SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand("SavePeople", objConnection);
        objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@peopleName", peopleName);       
        objConnection.Open();
        objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();       
      }
      return true;
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      //You want to log the ex
   }
   return false; 
}
```

Comment: Instead of creating a stored procedure, is there not a way i can just code it in to the method ?

Comment: @user1353517: Do the same thing in code. Create a method to get a user record using a select query. Check record exist. If yes execute Update statement, else insert. I prefer Stored proc approach

Comment: I think you should do this in a transaction, without a transaction in a multi-user situation it can happen than the `select` does not find anything, but before executing the `insert` another process creates the row - and you are back to duplicates

Comment: @MiMo: Agree. I just threw a generic idea to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

There is.  If you are familiar with Linq, it gives you a way to do this check very easily.  I'm taking a few shortcuts with the code you already know how to do.

```
string checkname = "Fred";
var x = tblPeople.Where(w => w.people == checkname);
if (x.Count > 0) 
{
  x.occur++;
  [databaseconnectionstring].SubmitChanges();
}
else 
{
  [insert your new record here]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, 1st you have to read the current value (using SELECT query), then create an UPDATE sql statement, which will update field in db. Increment it by one each time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can update the db`s field by the code:

```
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connString"))
        {
            int counter = 0;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT people FROM tblPeople", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.GetValue(0) != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        counter = (int)reader[0];
                    }
                }
            }
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblPeople SET people = @myCounter", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@myCounter", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = ++counter;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

1st: read current value (if exists)
2nd increment it by one and update the field

Hope it helps.
bye

Comment: I'm not sure how i'd fit in the Occur column table to this